# Why was the Asia Cup format changed from 50-over to Twenty20?

Tags: cricket

I don't understand it. The Asia Cup tournament has been played as a 50 over tournament for a long time, but has suddenly been changed to 20 over format.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone knew the format not changed suddenly.It changed for a quite a good reason. However, down to its timing and proximity to the World T20. Since it is scheduled to end a few days before that major event, it was felt to be convenient for every team to use it as a warm-up tournament. The conditions in Fatullah and Mirpur would be similar to what most of these teams would face in India during the World T20, and in any case most of these teams don't really play a lot of T20 internationals in Indian soil recently, so this would be a proper exercise to gear up ahead of a major tournament.

In my opinion people love to watch T20 these days anyhow and everyone wants one of the Asian team should be in the final T20 to spice up the game. So just  sit back and enjoy the new format of cricket and support your nation ahead of T20 WC...

Comment: Can you provide some documents to justify your reply?

Answer (score 5):

While Joe's answer is correct, the Asia Cup will not permanently be a T20 tournament. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Asia_Cup#Background) tells us that the recently revived Asia Cup tournament will be played on rotation basis in One Day International (ODI) and Twenty20 International (T20I) format based on respective next world events under the ICC.